# Get the group ID sorted from "/etc/group"

Tags: python-3.x, centos

I'd like to manipulate the "/etc/group"

```
In [39]: fp = open("/etc/group")
In [40]: content = [c.replace("\n", "") for c in fp.readlines()]
In [42]: content
Out[42]: 
['root:x:0:',
 'bin:x:1:',
 'daemon:x:2:',
 'sys:x:3:',
 'adm:x:4:',
 'tty:x:5:',
 'disk:x:6:',
 'lp:x:7:',
 'mem:x:8:',
 'kmem:x:9:',
 'wheel:x:10:',
 'cdrom:x:11:',
 'mail:x:12:postfix',
 'man:x:15:',
 'dialout:x:18:',....]
```

The result is sorted by alphabet rather than the group ID

```
In [44]: sorted(content, key=lambda c:int(re.search(r"\d+",c).group()))
Out[44]: 
['root:x:0:',
 'bin:x:1:',
 'daemon:x:2:',
 'sys:x:3:',
 'adm:x:4:',
 'tty:x:5:',
 'disk:x:6:',
 'lp:x:7:',
 'mem:x:8:',
 'kmem:x:9:',
 'wheel:x:10:',
 'cdrom:x:11:',
 'mail:x:12:postfix',
 'man:x:15:',
 'dialout:x:18:',
```

I get it done with re.search and lambda in a unwired way,
Could it be solved in an elegant style?

Comment: Is this in Linux or MacOS environment?
This gives the error 
orted(content, key=lambda c:int(re.search(r"\d+", c).group()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in MacOS environment

Comment: on remote CentOS server @Kalanamith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by the third colon-defined field:

```
sorted(content, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[2]))
```